# How to create two JVMs on one machine by different addresses

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, rmi

I want to simulate java rmi on my computer and for that I need two separate JVM which are running on one version of eclipse , please tell me how can I do that and how to set unique address for each of the JVMs

Comment: Please share your what you have done so far and what issues you have run into.

Comment: Do you need more than one Server? For local simulation normally you need one server and one client which are two different java code with main methods. Running each one will create an instance of jvm. If you need more than one server you should run a different copy of you server code with a different port to bind the instance of your service code.

Comment: `127.0.0.1`, `127.0.0.2`, `127.0.0.3`, ...

Answer (score 0):

> I want to simulate java rmi on my computer and for that I need two separate JVM

No you don't.

> which are running on one version of eclipse,

You don't need that either.

> please tell me how can I do that and how to set unique address for each of the JVMs

Or that. It doesn't matter in the least about the client IP address, and the server IP address is simply 127.0.0.1 for purposes of the Registry.

Just run the server program and then the client program. I do this in a single IDE all the time.

Everything you have been told about needing a separate physical or virtual machine is BS.